# QR-Scanning built with HTML5 & javascript, Turned into phone app with phonegap build?

Tags: html, qr-code, phonegap-build, getusermedia

Seen many posts on this around the web but no nearer finding out if it's possible to do...

Have seen http://www.webqr.com/ recommended but I tried uploading the .zip from github (https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode) for this to phonegap and the compiled app fails on android with "Sorry, native web camera streaming (getusermedia) is not supported by this browser"

Well, I'm not trying to use the webcam really, I want to access the camera on the phone/ipad if possible.

Is it actually possible to do this from HTML5 or does it require a proper native app? (so xcode for the ipad app I have in mind)

I've also seen some plugins for "phonegap" (as opposed to phonegap build) which would also require a mac/xcode so that's not the angle I want to approach it from as I'm trying to do this all from windows if possible.

Comment: If you like Windows you could use Xamarin (C#) (which uses native code) to code for iPad. Pretty sure this is not possible with HTML5 - and even if it was, the performance would probably suck.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that at all. Looking at it now, thanks!

Comment: Ah. At $999 for a business license to integrate into visual studio, no thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may help. it a js plugin. search the phonegap plugin page for 'scanners'

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/2421

https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/tree/c74e37a